# undefined method `receive_message_chain'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mocking

Surprisingy can't find anything about this.

Trying to stub this chain of methods:

```
Twitter::REST::Client.new(<some credentials>).user.followers_count
```

What I actually want to do is this:

```
allow_any_instance_of(Twitter::REST::Client).to receive_message_chain(:user, :followers_count).and_return 0
```

But it did not work. Gave an error `undefined method 'receive_message_chain'`.

So I found this tutorial on Rspec-Mocks 3.0: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/blob/master/features/method_stubs/receive_message_chain.feature

And tried this:

```
subject = Twitter::REST::Client
allow(subject).to receive_message_chain(:user, :followers_count).and_return 0
expect(Twitter::REST::Client.new.users.followers_count).to eq 0
```

Just to try it out - and it did not work either. Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

I do have `rspec-mocks (3.0.0.beta1)` in my `Gemfile.lock`.

Other types of stubs (like `.to receive(:method)` work fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method `receive_message_chain` was introduced in 3.0.0.beta2, as described in https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/blob/master/Changelog.md#300beta2--2014-02-17, so if you upgrade your version of `rspec-mocks` (currently at 3.0.0.rc1), you should be ok with that syntax.